# Is there a way to make media player keep on playing when I open new stage?

Tags: java, javafx

I've got this code:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    .......
    .....
    Media media = new Media(Paths.get("resources/x.mp3").toUri().toString()); 
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
    player.play();
}
```

When the application runs and i'm get into "help" in menu bar, the music stops.
is there a way to make it keep playing? or to continue when I get out of "help" window?

Comment: Try playing this video in a thread